# Image size smaller than recommended size - AMP Warning

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, amp

I installed AMP version on the website and newly find out the issue which is **Image size smaller than recommended size**. How to solve this?

Comment: Check to https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images and https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016

Comment: Thanks... bt can u solve this problem self practically?